# different return type and signature in Strategy Pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am bit confuse to use Strategy Pattern in my below case.

I have MyEntity class which is below.

```
public class MyEntity {

    private long id;
    private long userid;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
// other fields
```

I have below scenario that

1. `getMyEntity (long user_id)` which accepts user_id as parameter and return List which have same user_id from database.
2. `updateMyEntity (MyEntity myEntity )` which accepts MyEntity as parameter and update this MyEntity in database.
3. `deleteMyEntity (long id)` which accepts ID as parameter and delete this MyEntity in database.
4. `addMyEntity (MyEntity myEntity )` which accepts MyEntity as parameter and add this MyEntity in database.

Strategy Pattern with Java with above requirement. I can use Strategy Pattern in Java if method has similar input parameter and similar output parameter. But for my case I have different input parameter and different output parameter so I am confuse that how can I use Strategy Pattern.
Please guide me on this case.

Comment: If the pattern does not fit your use case, then why use it?

Comment: If a pattern doesn't seem to apply to a problem, why do you think that you should just continue to hammer that proverbial square peg into a round hole?

Comment: Dude I m not recommend to use primitive types for the primary key field like `long` and you should use `Long` instead of `long`

Comment: and please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062957/how-does-generation-type-identity-work-how-does-it-know-whats-the-next-primary it is useful 

if you mention `IDENTITY` strategy, then, database can automatically assign a next value

Comment: I have to use  Strategy Pattern with this requirement. Is there a way so that I can use it ?

Comment: @DhavalGoti no. It makes absolutely no sense. Ask whoever told you to use the strategy pattern to explain and clarify why he/she thinks it's a good idea, and how to use it.

Comment: (Additionally, Spring Data will implement all of this logic for you automatically.)

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is only tangentially programming-related, I think it is important to professional programmers.

The strategy pattern is a behavioral pattern, i.e. it is used to change how a (certain part of a) program behaves. Defining the CRUD-methods as behavior sound very, very counter-intuitive to me. You could define an abstract behavior and implement each CRUD-operation as a concrete instantiation of this behavior, but I do not want to imagine the level of abstraction necessary for such a solution.

Since you "*have to use Strategy Pattern*", you should go and talk to the person that gave you this limitation. Ask her/him to explain how to use the strategy pattern in this case. And now comes the important part: **If s*he is not able to explain why and how to use it, then don't use it**. And communicate clearly that you will not use it. Maybe even rebuttal the argument.

You are a professional. A major part of your job is to say "no", when a "no" is in order. And if something programming-related seems unreasonable to you after you have asked for clarification, then a "no" is definitely in order.

Comment: Can we use any different other pattern for input and different  other pattern for output ? Other than Strategy Pattern.

Comment: If the use case is the transformation from input to output itself (i.e. not the side-effects happening during the call), then you could call it a converter, though I do not know any specific pattern for this. If, however, the side effects are the main use case (like, e.g., when storing or updating something in/from database), I would not try to "unify" those use cases. You loose meaning by unifying everything under an abstract `T execute(U u)`-method.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy pattern doesn't seem to apply in your case.
You should read about the gold hammer anti pattern : https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-golden-hammer-anti-pattern-primers/

But if you really want to apply it you can change your methods signatures so that you can pass only Contact parameters.